# Python3 how to asyncio.gather() a list of partial functions

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm attempting to create a list of coroutines that can be passed to asyncio.gather()

However, I want to attach arguments to these coroutines as I append them to the list.

My current method shown below uses functools.partial. Unfortunately asyncio.gather doesn't accept a partial function, which makes sense.

What doesn't make sense to me is how to find a solution.

Example code:

```
async def test(arg1):
    print(arg1)

statements = []

function = functools.partial(test, "hello world")
statements.append(function)

results = await asyncio.gather(*statements)
```

So how do I attach arguments to a function so that it can still be passed to asyncio.gather?

*EDIT

It seems I was being rather silly.

My solution was rather simple, don't use functools.partial and just append the coroutine straight to the list.

Code:

```
async def test(arg1):
    print(arg1)

async def main():
    statements = []
    statements.append(test("hello_world"))
    results = await asyncio.gather(*statements)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Gathering results of multiple async function calls only once

If you need to run a sequence of `async` function calls only once, you can simply store their immediately returned coroutine objects in a list, pass the unpacked list to `asyncio.gather` and then `await` to collect final return values from coroutines.

```py
async def upper_cased(value: str) -> str:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return value.upper()

coroutines = [
    upper_cased("h"),
    upper_cased("e"),
    upper_cased("l"),
    upper_cased("l"),
    upper_cased("o"),
    upper_cased(" "),
    upper_cased("w"),
    upper_cased("o"),
    upper_cased("r"),
    upper_cased("l"),
    upper_cased("d"),
]
print("".join(await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)))
# prints HELLO WORLD
```

This works because unlike ordinary functions, calling an `async` function (without awaiting) doesn't start executing it, it just returns an object that contains all the necessary details of the function call including argument values. This object can be used later to complete its execution in different ways, one of them is using `await`.

#### Gathering results of multiple async function calls multiple times

If you need to run the same sequence of `async` functions (with predetermined arguments) **multiple times**, simply storing their return values in a list and then passing the unpacked list to `asyncio.gather` **will not work**.

This is because coroutine objects can only be awaited once. Awaiting them again when they have already returned values will raise a `RuntimeError`.

```py
async def random_cased(value: str) -> str:
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
        return value.upper()
    return value.lower()

coroutines = [
    random_cased("h"),
    random_cased("e"),
    random_cased("l"),
    random_cased("l"),
    random_cased("o"),
    random_cased(" "),
    random_cased("w"),
    random_cased("o"),
    random_cased("r"),
    random_cased("l"),
    random_cased("d"),
]
print("".join(await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)))
# prints HeLlO wOrLd (or any other random cased variation)

print("".join(await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)))
# raises RuntimeError (cannot reuse already awaited coroutine)
```

For this case, you can use `functools.partial` objects to store both the `async` functions and their argument values.

```py
partial_funcs = [
    functools.partial(random_cased, "h"),
    functools.partial(random_cased, "e"),
    functools.partial(random_cased, "l"),
    functools.partial(random_cased, "l"),
    functools.partial(random_cased, "o"),
    functools.partial(random_cased, " "),
    functools.partial(random_cased, "w"),
    functools.partial(random_cased, "o"),
    functools.partial(random_cased, "r"),
    functools.partial(random_cased, "l"),
    functools.partial(random_cased, "d"),
]
print("".join(await asyncio.gather(*[func() for func in partial_funcs])))
# prints HeLlO wOrLd (or any other random cased variation)

print("".join(await asyncio.gather(*[func() for func in partial_funcs])))
# prints HeLlO wOrLd (or any other random cased variation)

print("".join(await asyncio.gather(*[func() for func in partial_funcs])))
# prints HeLlO wOrLd (or any other random cased variation)
```

You can also use other containers instead of `functools.partial` if you want. For example, a list for storing functions and another list for storing their arguments.

Answer (score 19):

> However, I want to attach arguments to these coroutines as I append them to the list.

You can simply *call* the coroutine functions with their requisite arguments. Unlike ordinary functions (but similar to generators), calling the coroutine function doesn't start executing it, it just returns an object that can be used to drive its execution later. This object already captures the invocation arguments and can be added to the list passed to `asyncio.gather`.

For example:

```
statements = []

statements.append(test("hello world"))
# ...

results = await asyncio.gather(*statements)
```

**Note:** This will not work in case you need to gather results from the functions multiple times. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65755581/14733755) for a solution to this special case.

Comment: it works, thanks! https://gist.github.com/hclivess/1de8d17dafddf089f5954b6b282c03e7